# How to serialize URL and make it still readable in PHP?

Tags: php, serialization

I need to serialize array which contains URLs:

Array(
  'url1' => 'http://www.example.com',
  'url2' => 'http://www.example1.com'
)
and store it in DB.

When I serialize it standard way, it doesn't work as it contains special chars. I found solution to encode it with base64_encode . Then it works but string is unreadable from me in DB manager program. Is there a way to make this work without base64_decode ?

Comment: Please be more specific: how *exactly* "it doesn't work"? This is rather essential.

Comment: `json_encode` might be an alternative.. But I don't see why `serialize()` would make an URL unreadable in the first place. Can you make an example?

Comment: Your problem is most likely coming from the quotes/double-quotes PHP (and JSON) serialization mechanism uses. This leads me to believe that you are not escaping the data properly when inserting it into the database (i.e.: with `mysql_real_escape_string`, PDO, or equivalent).

Comment: Your /real/ question should be 'How do I normalize this datastructure'? Attempting to store two values in some format in a database is a database design / normalization smell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It should always set off a red flag when you're trying to store serialized data in a   relational database. Normalize your schema so you don't have to serialize.
2. Storing your data in a poor format so it is readable while in the DB is not a good idea. You want to store it in a format that is the most efficient for database system, then update your manager to unserialize it when you are ready yo display.
3. `json_encode` is popular these days, and helps make your data portable.

Comment: If you don't need anything "relational" out of the data you're saving, it is an overkill to normalize your data to be relational. Sometimes just sticking serialized data into a column works wonders.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PHP 5+, try using JSON instead of the native PHP serializer. JSON is a lot more portable.

But your problem could be with automatic escaping of quotes. It would be helpful if you can show examples of your input & output to/from the DB.

Comment: I love that "try using" **without slightest understanding what certain problem is.** How do you know if json would work? Do you know any certain case where json would work but serialize wouldn't?

Comment: Ergo, the answer asks for more clarification from the OP, while proposing something to try with the idea that it could save the OP some time.

Comment: Any reason your proposal could save the OP some time. I was asking for it already, if you didn't notice.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: "But your problem could be with automatic escaping of quotes" is indicative of _some_ understanding of (or at least past experience with) the problem. I appreciate your being pedantic about the content of answers, but you're not being more constructive than I have been in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason why serialize shouldn't work on this example, so it may be more to do with adequate escaping of inputs in your SQL query rather than an issue with the kind of serialisation you're doing.  If you're using MySQL, try running the serialised data through [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) before you concatenate it into your SQL statement.

Separately, I tend to prefer json_encode() for serialisation of values to a DB field, because serialise tends to make serialised data that is very hard to read manually, and extremely difficult to edit.